# Find date difference in hours?

Tags: typescript

I have a case where I need to check the diff of the hours between two Date-time.
I am new in typescript but in java, I have done something like below just a small example to show you what I need.

```
  int hours = (int) ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(app.getDisableAt(), LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
```

And I need the same thing but in front-end. By this, I get the hour's diff correctly, but I don't want to save in database so I prefer the front-end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: I tried those ones but didn't get the correct result otherwise why would I ask here, anyway thank you

Comment: @IliaTapia you want a hours difference between current datetime and what ?

Comment: Can you please write what has you already tried @ilia-tapia ? :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular, so I removed the tag and added JS instead.

Comment: you need only hours or hh:mm:ss?

Comment: I have tried  common examples ` const diff = Math.abs(this.catalog.disableAt.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 3600000;` , this looks good but i get an error for `getTime() , that is not a function'.

Comment: @Chaitanya only the hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert into epoch date and get difference between two dates and divide by 1000*3600

```
getDateDiffInHours(date1: Date, date2: Date) {
        return Math.floor((new Date(date2).getTime() - new Date(date1).getTime()) / 3600000);
      }
```